# tkinter Radiobuttons not displaying value in class

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter, inheritance

I'm currently a college student learning python and am stuck with some `Radiobutton` issues using tkinter. When using multiple classes my radiobuttons won't update their values and will always print out the `.set()` method's value. This is a snippet of code similar to what I have in my lab but its just the problem area.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class test(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.TOPNUM=15


class dialogWindow(test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rc=tk.IntVar()
        self.rc.set(20)


        self.radio1=tk.Radiobutton(self,text="1",value=1,variable=self.rc,command=self.rc.get())
        self.radio2=tk.Radiobutton(self,text="2",value=2,variable=self.rc,command=self.rc.get())

        self.button=tk.Button(self,text="CLick Me!",command=lambda : self.clicked(self.rc.get()))

        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.rc.set(20)

    def clicked(self,value):
        print(value)


def run():
    win=test()
    win.title("Top Colleges")
    win.minsize(200,200)
    header=tk.Label(win,text="College Lookup",fg="blue",font=15)
    header.pack()

    dataButton=tk.Button(win,text="By Data",width=8, command= lambda : dialogWindow())

    dataButton.pack()

    win.mainloop()

run()
```

However, when I tried writing it in just a single class instead it does work and I can't figure out why.

```
class dialogWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rc=tk.IntVar()
        self.rc.set(20)

        self.radio1=tk.Radiobutton(self,text="1",value="1",variable=self.rc,command=self.rc.get())
        self.radio2=tk.Radiobutton(self,text="2",value="2",variable=self.rc,command=self.rc.get())

        self.button=tk.Button(self,text="CLick Me!",command=lambda : self.clicked(self.rc.get()))

        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.rc.set(1)

    def clicked(self,value):
        print(value)


def run():
    win=dialogWindow()
    win.minsize(200,200)
    dataButton=tk.Button(win,text="By Data",width=8, command= lambda:dialogWindow())

    dataButton.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5)

    win.mainloop()
run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is quite simple, there is two instances of `Tk()` created because of inheritance. Now you have to specify which instance the `IntVar()` should belong to, because it always sets itself to the first created instance(`win`), but here you don't want that. So:

```
class dialogWindow(test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.rc=tk.IntVar(self)
        .....
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. Thank you for that and for the explanation!